# Can't set the custom static cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to set a custom cell so I created the CustomDetailCell class and a cell on the storyboard where I've created 2 UILabel. For the labels I change the font and the size and connect the custom class with the cell on the storyboard. I try to use it like this:

```
case DetailControllerAddressSection:
{
    CustomDetailCell *customCell = (CustomDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"AddressCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    customCell.addresLabel.text = [self.objectData pointSubtitle];
    customCell.distanceLabel.text = [self distanceMessageForObjectData: self.objectData];
    return customCell;
    break;
}
```

But on my cell there is only one label with the other font (not like in storyboard cell)

Can't understand this.. Any help?

PS The identifier for the cell is used in storyboard.

EDIT: Custom controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomDetailCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceLabel;

@end

#import "CustomDetailCell.h"

@implementation CustomDetailCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged your cell implementation?  I recently had issues (under OSX) with a custom cell as I hadn't implemented all the `init` methods mentioned in the docs and therefore some of the instance variables didn't get initialised.

Comment: Do you have connect also **IBOutlet**? Or how do you take the labels from code? If yes, i need to see the custom class and the viewcontroller's picture in the storyboard.

Comment: I've edited my question - the cell is highlighted.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some drawing code in the subclass?